# Difficulty in verifying bitcoin-core signing keys

Tags: bitcoin-core, signature, message-signing

How can I verify *bitcoin0.19* signature bwith `gpg`?
I read I should use `gpg --recv-keys signingkey`, but I don't understand where is the file `signiggkey`. I tried to download *Bitcoin Core Release Signing Keys v0.11.0+* but what I got is a `.asc` file, which I don't know how to use

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the `.asc` file, you can do

```
gpg --import <asc filename>
```